# Conjugated subgroups question

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For a group $G$ and subgroup $H \subset G$, is it true that $aHa^{-1} = bHb^{-1} \Leftrightarrow aH = bH$ for any $a,b \in G$? I am trying to establish an injection between the set of conjugated subgroups of G in H, and the set of cosets $G/H$, to show that the cardinality of the former is less than or equal to $index[G:H]$.

Comment: No, it's not true. You might want to consider the normalizer subgroup $N(H) = \{a\in G: aHa^{-1} = H\}$.

Comment: How could you use this to show the result?

Comment: Have you learned about orbits and stabilizers? If so, use it. If not, I don't know. :)

Comment: Indeed, I hadn't associated it yet but sounds like a good idea! Thanks a lot! :)